# set max file size for upload - el_finder for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elfinder

I can't find where to set the maximum upload file size. There's a variable or some initializer I ignored? Could you help me?
Nunzio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails itself doesn't has a limit or rather a way to set one.

**elFinder** has a variable called **uploadMaxSize**. Look up the [Connector configuration options](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options) of elFinder for further information [here](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options#wiki-uploadMaxSize).

For **PaperClip** use the validator called validates_attachment_size. Example Usage can be found [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) under Validations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using carrierwave, this will be helpful.
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-attachment-file-size

Comment: I use paperclip. I'll search for uploadMaxSize as suggested from @florianbussmann

Comment: For PaperClip use the validator called validates_attachment_size. Example Usage can be found [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) under Validations.